# void insert(int ) method for BST tree/C++

Tags: c++

I have been trying to get this function working for the longest time now.  It is part of an assignment for an online course, but it seems no matter what I submit, the function fails for both the empty child test and the left child test.  See code below.  The `main()` function is deliberately commented out.  Any info./input is much appreciated.

```
// C++ binary trees and stuff;
//
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class BST
{
    public:
        int data;
        BST *left;
        BST *right;
        //BST *root;
        // BST() constructor
        BST (int num)
        {
            data = num;
            left = nullptr;
            right = nullptr;
            root = nullptr;
        }
        // constructors for root node(s), initializing as root when no values exist yet;
        BST() : root (nullptr){}
        BST (BST *rootNode) : root(rootNode){}
        void insert (int value)
        {
            BST *newNode = new BST();
            newNode = root;
            if (root == nullptr)
            {
                root = new BST (value);
            }
            else
            {
                root->data = value;
            }
            // check if newNode's value equals the passed-in value:
            if (value == root->data)
            {
                //cout << "\nWarning!  Value already exists in tree, so nothing will be done.\n";
                return;
            }
            // check if value is < or > newNode's value:
            if (value <= root->data)
            {
                if (root->left == nullptr)
                {
                    // make a new node as the left child of this node,
                    root->left = new BST(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    // recursively call insert() on tree's left side,
                    root->left->insert(value);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (root->right == nullptr)
                {
                    // make a new node as the right child of this node,
                    root->right = new BST(value);
                }
                else
                {
                    // recursively call insert() on tree's right side,
                    root->right->insert(value);
                }
            }
        }
    public:
        BST *root;
};
/*
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //...insert code here,
    
    // create nodes,...
    
    BST rootNode(5);
    BST leftNode(4);
    BST rightNode(6);
    // connect the nodes to the tree via rootNode.left and rootNode.right,..
    
    rootNode.left = &leftNode;
    rootNode.right = &rightNode;
    printf ("\nData (root) value = %i, rootNode.left = %i, and rootNode.right = %i\n",
            rootNode.data, rootNode.left->data, rootNode.right->data);
    cout << "\n\nHello, Solar System!\n";
    return 0;
}
*/
```

Comment: Please follow the tour [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks), [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67061144/edit) your question and make your code readable.

Comment: Reading your code out loud: "First, create a `BST` with an indeterminate value and point `newNode` at it. Then point `newNode` at the root instead of the new node. If the tree is empty, create another new `BST` with the inserted value and point `root` at it, otherwise overwrite the previous value in the root with the value to insert. Then, if the value to insert is the same as the value in the root, return." You should be able to spot a few problems with that procedure.

Comment: The shown class suffers from a major identify crisis/psychosis. It doesn't know whether it wants to be a node in a binary tree, or represent the binary tree itself with a pointer to the root node. The shown class's major identify crisis must be fixed; until that happens there will be nothing but confusion and mysterious bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my suggestion. You need to reformat your code. You need two classes. You need a BST, and you need a Node. The various methods to add/remove/traverse are part of the BST class. Nodes are just Nodes.

So:

```
class BST_Node {
public:
    int value;
    BST_Node * left = nullptr;
    BST_Node * right = nullptr;

    // Define constructors, etc.
};

class BST {
public:
     BST_Node * root = nullptr;

     BST_Node * insert(int value);
     void insertNode(BST_Node *node);
     void insertNodeBelow(BST_Node *nodeToInsert, BST_Node *startingNode);
};

BST_Node * BST::insert(int value) {
    BST_Node * node = new BST_Node(value);
    insertNode(node);
    return node;
}

void BST::insertNode(BST_Node *node) {
    if (node == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (root == nullptr) {
        root = node;
    }
    else {
        insertNodeBelow(node, root);
    }
}

void BST::insertNodeBelow(BST_Node *node, BST_Node *startingNode) {
    if (node == nullptr || startingNode == nullptr) {
        return;
    }
    if (node->value < startingNode->value) {
        if (startingNode->left != nullptr) {
            insertNodeBelow(node, startingNode->left);
        }
        else {
            startingNode->left = node;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (startingNode->right != nullptr) {
            insertNodeBelow(node, startingNode->right);
        }
        else {
            startingNode->right = node;
        }
    }
}
```

How this works... First, the logic of how to store nodes is in BST. Nodes don't care. Second, I made methods for either inserting a value or a node. Because I think that's handy. That should be fairly easy to understand.

The root node can be null, if so, then your inserted node is now root. Otherwise it calls the recursive insertion function. Now, you could simplify this a little, but I didn't want to get too clever.

So it's simple. We look to see where it belongs relative to the point we're at (initially the root). Either we go into the left branch or the right branch. But that branch could be empty, so you just plop it right in. If it's not empty, then you recurse.

I didn't test it.